# Checksum calculation in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, byte, checksum

The checksum are computed according to the following formula:

> Checksum = INV (data byte 1 ⊕ data byte 2 ⊕ ... ⊕ data byte 8)

To form the checksum, the individual data bytes are added by modulo-256 arithmetic. This involves adding overrun bits to the specific intermediate result. Finally, the overall result is inverted.
My attempt(i took this hex numbers as an exmaple, correct result of those numbers is  &H33"):

```
  Private Sub Button46_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button46.Click
        Dim Sum As Byte = 0
        Dim Bytes() As Short = {&H22, &H22, &HAA, &HAA, &H55, &H55, &H44, &H44}
        For I As Integer = 0 To Bytes.Length - 1
            Sum += Bytes(I) Mod 10
        Next
        Sum = Not (Sum)
        RichTextBox1.Text = Hex(Sum.ToString)
    End Sub
```

Shows me an overflow exception.Also i dont know how to "add overrun bits" Any ideas?

Comment: You can't store the result of an addition in a data type that is too small to contain it. If you add two `Byte` values together and the result is bigger than the maximum value a `Byte` variable can store, you'll get an overflow exception if you try to store it in a `Byte` variable. Presumably, you need to convert each `Byte` to a `Short` so that the result will be a `Short` and not overflow if the value is too big for a `Byte`. After each sum, take the `Mod` and do the same for the next. After the final `Mod`, you can convert back to a `Byte`.

Comment: you should listen to @jmcilhinney. You have the answer in front of you. You a byte array containing 8 time 1 byte so 8 bytes. Then you are making a For/next loop to add them into a 1 byte memory spot. The only difference is visually you have them horizontally showing your byte array and vertically in your for/next loop. I agree with your logic that the result of your math formula is the size of a byte but you need the space to work before giving the answer. It's like cutting a sheet of plywood in a full garage, it would work better in a bigger space.

Comment: i added the topic, with changes. Besides i dont know how to convert short to the byte. The changes shows me "DD" as result while it should be "33". Also @jmcilhinney, how to add overrun bits? For example: we are add byte1 + byte2 + byte3+ byte4+ byte5 + byte6+ byte7+byte8, so it means &H22 + &H22  = &H44, then &H44 + &HAA  = &HEE, then &HEE+ &HAA  = &H198 - its where overflow starts, btw we have to add all bytes first to the sum. So next is &H198+ &H55  = &H1ED, then &H1ED+ &H55  = &H242, then  &H242+ &H44  = &H286, and final byte: &H286+ &H44  = &H2CA.

Comment: @jmcilhinney,  we have 2CA,  then we have to sum "2" and "A" = CC, then INVERT CC, and done = &H33 = CORRECT RESULT. Thats the most difficult part, i dont know to do it programmly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to track the overflow and modulo separately, if you want to add them.  That's not what your 1st line '`Checksum = INV (data byte 1 ⊕ data byte 2 ⊕ ... ⊕ data byte 8)`' indicates though - are you sure?  Code would be like this (gives `&H33`):

```
Dim sum As Integer = 0
Dim bytes() As Byte = {&H22, &H22, &HAA, &HAA, &H55, &H55, &H44, &H44}
For i As Integer = 0 To bytes.Length - 1
    sum += bytes(i)
Next
Dim overflow = sum \ 256
Dim modulo = sum Mod 256
sum = Not (CByte((overflow + modulo) Mod 256))
```